# Getting data stored in additional field of googlemap's marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps api and javascript which I am not much familiar with. Here's the code I use to draw markers on my map. I get Latitudes and Longitudes from my database:

```
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var jsonStr = '<?php echo json_encode($arajka) ?>';
    var LatLong = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.000001, 20.000001),
          zoom: 12
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        var marker = [];

        for(var i=0;i<LatLong.length;i++){

           var LatLong1 = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLong[i].lat, LatLong[i].lon);
        marker.ajdi=LatLong[i].id; // storing additional data (I need to get it when user clicks on certain marker)
           marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({position: LatLong1, map: map, title: LatLong[i].login}));

        }
                    // trying to set some listener but it fails.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(8);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            alert("ASDASDASD" + marker.ajdi);
        });
    }
```

So, this listener doesn't work, I don't know why. Well, I expect that it doesn't exactly know what marker is it about. When I tried to do it with a single one, like in tutorial, it worked properly. I don't know what to do when I have this array. Any suggestions please?

Comment: In this scope `marker` is an array. Does `addListener` attach the event to each item in the array?

Comment: This Listener coded by me doesn't work at all. First of all I wanted to check if it can do anything (like zooming map), turned out it couldn't. My goal is to get that marker.ajdi out of clicked one. Simply: every marker has .ajdi field added. After clicking on each, I want to retrieve his .ajdi.

Comment: Also, you're not assigning the `ajdi` property to each marker in the loop, but to the `marker` array. Try creating the marker with a new var, then adding the property, then pushing it into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code:

1. As @Hollister mentions, `marker` is an array, so you need to put the addListener call inside the loop;
2. You have to store the additional marker data into the marker, not into the marker array;
3. you have to use `this` in the listener, not `marker`.

   ```
   for(var i=0;i<LatLong.length;i++){

      var LatLong1 = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLong[i].lat, LatLong[i].lon);
      var this_marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: LatLong1, map: map, title: LatLong[i].login});
      this_marker.ajdi=LatLong[i].id; // storing additional data (I need to get it when user clicks on certain marker)
      marker.push(this_marker);

               // trying to set some listener but it fails.
      google.maps.event.addListener(this_marker, 'click', function() {
          map.setZoom(8);
          map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
          alert("ASDASDASD" + this.ajdi);
      });
   }
   ```

Comment: You are definitely right, I should do this_marker.ajdi = LatLong[i].id; But I have doubts if it would make Listener works. Gonna try it now

Comment: Tried it and worked but only for that last one marker. I mean the last added. Every previous one seems to be not reacting on clicks. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you notice that the `addListener` is *inside* the loop? If you are sure you have it inside, post a code in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: No problem, fortunatelly I was able to *guess* where your mistake is :-)

Comment: Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/cfL2U/) for reference.